# Does spring data elasticsearch support saving a inner object as a new document

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

```
@Document(indexName = "test", type = "author")
public class Author {
   private String authorId;
   private List<Book> books;
}

@Document(indexName = "test", type = "book")
public class Book {
   private String bookId;
}
```

Using spring data elasticsearch when i save the Author i want the Book to be saved in a different entity rather than a sub-document. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you need to store the book ids instead of the Book entity. Non-relational data store don't support foreign keys like RDB.

```
@Document(indexName = "test", type = "author")
public class Author {
   private String authorId;
   private List<String> bookIds;
}
```

Plus by doing this books are not indexed along with author. You'll get performance penalty if you try to search "author writing a book with specific title", whereas if you nest it ES will index author.book.title.

The [Denormalizing your Data section of ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html) has a nice explanation of this